# Local variable within for-loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

Is it possible to define local a variable within a for-loop, so that it cannot be accessed outside the loop? In the following simple example, what should I do so that `index` is not defined outside the loop?

```
input<-rnorm(10)
output<-rep(NA,10)

for(i in 1:10){
     index<-1:i
     output[i]<-sum(input[index])^2
     }
```

Comment: null it after it leaves the loop?

Comment: To completely remove it, you could use `rm(index)` as the last step.

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: I assume there is more to your question but why not use: output[i]<-sum(input[1:i])^2

Comment: you could put the loop in a function

Comment: @ Vincent: yes, there is more, it is just a simple example.
@Fernando: I use the same loop for different data, I want to avoid the danger of mixing them up...

Comment: @josilber do you mean putting `rm(index)` outside every loop?

Comment: The real solution, in R, is to avoid `for` loops and to use list functions like `Map` (or the `*apply` family) instead. There’s a broad consensus to avoid `for` in R completely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming this is just a toy example and your real situation is more complicated, you could wrap the for-loop in a call to `local`, and change the assignment operator acting on `output` to `<<-`.

```
local(
    for(i in 1:10){
         index<-1:i
         output[i] <<- sum(input[index])^2
         }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

You can `NULL` the variable after the use or remove, as was suggested in the comments, but if what you want to do is to encapsulate what a particular loop is doing, the best practice would be to put it into a function.  That way you can ensure that the scope of the variable is correct and you don't rely on yourself to remember to `NULL` the variable or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code in an new environment and run the function in this environment (with `evalq`):

```
input <- rnorm(10)
output <- rep(NA,10)

# create new environment
e1 <- new.env()

# run command in environment 'e1'
evalq(for(i in 1:10){
  index <- 1:i
  output[i] <- sum(input[index])^2
}, e1)

# assign value from 'output' in global environment
output <- get("output", e1)
```

The variable `i` is created in the environment `e1` only, not in the global environment.

Since the global environment is the parent of `e1`, you can access `input` and `output` inside `e1`.

Comment: It is not as simple :)

Comment: @RStudent See the update for a completely different approach.